# Unable to create a CoreContainer when embedding Solr in Jetty

Tags: java, solr, lucene, jetty

I followed the instructions on this post: http://javaskeleton.blogspot.de/2011/07/adding-solr-to-existing-web-application.html.

When I tried to execute this code:

```
File home = new File(System.getProperty("solr.solr.home"));
CoreContainer container = new CoreContainer(home.getPath());
container.load();
EmbeddedSolrServer server = new EmbeddedSolrServer(container, "collection1");
```

I encountered the following error:

> org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed
>   out:
>   NativeFSLock@C:\solr-4.6.0\example\solr\collection1\data\index\write.lock

Upon investigation, the error is issued while loading the CoreContainer. It attempts to lock a file in the index that is apparently locked.

Further investigation revealed that the SolrRequestFilter (the one that is initialized by Jetty) also instantiates a CoreContainer and my guess is that he is the offender. When I removed the SolrRequestFilter definition from web.xml, I was able to successfully instantiate the CoreContainer and the EmbeddedServer.

I am looking for insight as to how I can try to overcome the problem since it seems that it should be able to work.

Answer (score 0):

You must find who lock this index.

Also there are several approaches that might help:

- Since you starting embedded Solr, you need to be sure, that Solr isn't running now (my bet is that 99% this is the cause of this issue)
- You could remove this lock file manually